# Init/kconfig : Broken

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I am trying to build a minimal sized kernel. So I ran the command:

```
make tinyconfig
```

On top of this I want to include some additional modules like NFC client support which depends on something called BROKEN.

When I searched for BROKEN, it says:

```
symbol: BROKEN [=n]
Defined at: init/kconfig: 31
```

Question is how do I include it in my kernel?

The menu generated after running

```
make menuconfig
```

shows no option of init anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BROKEN` indicates that a driver is broken: it doesn't work and may not even compile. It's deliberate that you can't include it in your kernel. `CONFIG_BROKEN` is not supposed to be defined anywhere.

Look for a different version of the kernel where the drivers you need aren't marked as broken.

If you want to use a driver that's marked as BROKEN and you can't find a suitable kernel version, you should remove the dependency on `BROKEN` and start working on fixing the driver: first get it to build, then get it to run. Obviously that's an option only if you know Linux kernel programming.